# SQL DateTime Format Convert

Tags: sql-server, datetime

i want to change my datetime format on my MS SQL from the default format of 12-12-2000 13:01:01:0111 to **December 12, 2000 1:01AM**

this is my codes->

```
date_issued = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),date_issued,107) +' '+
              SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_issued,108),2,0)+
              LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),date_issued,100),7)),
```

**How can I convert it to December 12, 2000 1:01AM???**

Comment: Huh? Why would you expect it to lie and have AM rather than PM?

Comment: This is a job for your presentation layer e.g. reporting tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is to convert 'PM' text to 'AM', then simply use 'REPLACE', note that i used 'GETDATE()' in below examples

```
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),107) +'  '+
  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),108),2,0)+
  REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),getdate(),100),7)),'PM','AM')
```

If its **PM->AM and AM->PM** then try below

```
SELECT  "DateTime"=  
  CASE 
     WHEN patindex('%AM', CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100) ) =  0 THEN

       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),107) +'  '+
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),108),2,0)+
       REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),getdate(),100),7)),'PM','AM')

     ELSE 

       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate(),107) +'  '+
       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),108),2,0)+
       REPLACE(LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),getdate(),100),7)),'AM','PM')

  END
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a datetime field, you are not going to change the format of the date being stored that way.

You can achieve your output format this way, I used getdate because i am not sure what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT stuff(convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 100), 
       1, 3, datename(month, getdate()))
```